# How to use LIKE on inet field in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, sql-like, inet

I need to perform the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE ip LIKE '88.99.%';
```

The problem is that the `inet` datatype does not seems to support wildcards (at least not in the way I have utilized them in the preceding query).

What I'd like to know is whether it would be a smart move to convert the field into string before specifying the `LIKE` filter? (On the other hand, this would probably slow down the whole query, even if the approach itself was valid.)

Answer (score 31):

Use subnet operators for such queries. `'88.99.0.0/16'` should do it :

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE ip << inet '88.99.0.0/16';
```

Comment: Thanks. Any idea of how to use this in ORMs like SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 13):

Another option which worked for me if you want to do a string comparison is this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE TEXT(ip) LIKE '88.99.%';
```

although it will be less efficient than "[How to use LIKE on inet field in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190669/postgresql-like-on-inet-field/16190911#16190911)".

Reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-net.html

Comment: The datatype in this case is inet, try to avoid the cast of all data.

Comment: @FrankNStein, sometimes it's impossible to avoid. For example I want to search `%.10.%`, only this solution will work I suppose.

Comment: yep, that case is the worst scenario :(